# How can I provide password reset functionality in a secure way?

Tags: php, security, passwords

I'm currently finishing up a website where users are required to create a personal account in order to play a game that is hosted on the same website. What I'm currently having difficulty figuring out is how to implement secure password reset functionality for the users in the case of a forgotten password.

This is the process that is currently in place:

**Step 1**: User clicks on "Forgot Password" link on the website.
**Step 2**: User is brought to form and enters email address twice before being sent email.
**Step 3**: Email contains link to another form where the user can enter a new password twice for confirmation. Upon entering the second form, the system inserts a new record into my Recover_Password table in a database which contains the columns "id", "token", "created_at", and "expires_at".
This is the link -> (mywebsitename).com/form?id=99999&token=
Where "id" is the user's id and "token" is generated from `do_hash($id . date('Y-m-d'))`

**Step 4**: User completes form and is brought to the login page. The system clears the token record from the database and updates the user's current password from the user table.

Also I want to know what to do if the user tries refreshing the browser page when they are at the second form. I am currently only allowing access to the page if there is an id and a token value in the get parameters and that they both exist in the database.

I am using Codeigniter for the entire website and need to kow if this is a secure way of doing this and also how I should handle the token and the database. Thank you!!

Comment: "twice before being sent email." --- asking a user to repeat a email 4 times will make the solution even more secured

Comment: This is not answering the main question, but there's no reason to use a hash here. Especially not if it's easy to generate by an attacker. You can just use a really long random string instead, since you're checking against the database anyway.

Comment: Set a token expire time, delete the token after the users click submit... Have two randomly generated fields on the $_GET attr, `example.com/ChangePass.php?Token=&RefID=&UserID=?` and only allow a password change if refID and Token match the stored values.

Comment: 1. User inputs an email (just one time) 2. On email you send an auto-authorization  link. That is - user clicks it and is already authorized. Such a link expires after single usage or some short timeout (say an hour). Then user may change password in their profile, if they wish.

Comment: @zerkms Off topic, but I got the question resolved.. It randomly started working after a 4th hard reset.. I'm scared incase I have to restart the server now -.-

Comment: @zerkms I see a problem with that - If you allow auto-auth, you effectively grant anyone with access to the email a stealth account. The user would never know someone else is accessing the service, because the password would never be changed. Attacker can login to the account using the new token every time.

Comment: @viraptor Send an Email to the user, it's their fault if their E-mail is compromised. Theres alot you can control when it comes to sensitive data, but more you can't control

Comment: @viraptor: it's the core of a solution. Depending on a particular requirements you may demand a user to change the password

Comment: @DarylGill It's either their, or their provider's, or their sysadmin's, or their backup provider's, or their roommate's, or ... fault. Don't blame the user. If you only allow password resets, then at least any change will be obvious.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses, guys. Any type of advice or suggestion is helpful.

Comment: @zerkms By "asking a user to repeat an email 4 times" do you mean 4 times total on both forms, so twice per form?

Comment: @hRdCoder: it was irony. There is no reason to confirm email

Comment: @viraptor The hash I'm using is assumingly just as secure as a randomly generated string of the same length. It's the user's id along with the current date hashed in sha-1 format. This did cross my mind earlier but I presume it should be safe to keep it the way it is.

Comment: @zerkms Your right. Come to think of it, only one confirmation for the email should be good enough considering that it does check if the email is in the database. So if there was a typing error it wouldn't accept it anyways.

Comment: @hRdCoder: if you need something random - it's always a good idea to generate a pure random thing, not derive from some user (guessable) data. If you know user's id - you can easily generate the hash

Comment: @zerkms I'm surprised I didn't even think of that. Great suggestion, thanks! I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A secure way to handle password-resets could look like this:

---

Password reset request:

1. User opens password-reset request form and enters the email address (no need to enter it twice, just make a syntax validation).
2. Your application checks whether the email exists in your database. If it exists it creates a token, which should be random and not derrived from informations like userid or timestamp. A **hash of the token** will be stored in the database in a separate table, together with the userid and an expiry date. A link with the token is sent to the user per email.
3. The application shows a confirmation that the email was sent. This page can contain the email address, so the user can check if he had a typo (after all there was no information whether the email was in the database, so that an attacker cannot test its existence).

---

Password reset:

4. User clicks the link and opens the reset form. On this form he can enter the new password twice. The token has to be included as hidden input tag in the form.
5. After submitting the form, the application checks he token. If it matches and has not expired, the password can be changed and the user can be logged in directly (you can spare him the login form then). At last the token should be deactivated, i myself prefer to keep the entry, so i can inform the user that the token was already used, when he clicks the link again.

One problem you will encounter is, that you have to find the hash of the token in the database. There are two possible ways to store the token:

- You hash the token with a hash algorithm like SHA512 without a salt. This is secure if the token is very strong (minimum length 20 with 0-9 a-z A-Z). Theoretically you have to check whether such a hash already exists before you enter it in the database, in practise this is negligible. I implemented a [password-reset class](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#passwordreset) that can handle such tokens.
- You hash the token with BCrypt and salt. This allows for shorter tokens, but you cannot search for the hashed token in the database. Instead you have to include a row-id in the link to find the token.

Comment: Thanks for your well put and clear response, @martin. I do have a couple questions, though. 1. In step 2 of password reset request above you recommend not deriving the token from a user id or timestamp. What if the token is the date down to the second, hashed? This would make it different depending on the time of the day. And 2. Maybe I should include this in my original question, but how should the expiry for the token be handled? I've looked into it and its recommended that I use either a crontab (if Linux) or schedule an event in MySQL for the tokens. How would I do this?

Comment: @hRdCoder - To your first question, the problem is that the token becomes predictable then. If you know the approximate time the link was generated, you can narrow down the range of possible values badly. An attacker with read access to the db (SQL-injection) could bruteforce the token easily then. The second question can be solved much easier than you think. Just store the timestamp of the token creation in the database and then wait until somebody clicks the link. When the user finally tries to change the password, then check whether the token is still valid or not.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will give this a go and see how it goes. Thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts around the security of giving any indication of whether the email account exists or not?

Comment: @jontsai - Giving feedback about the existence of an email can make it easier for an attacker. 1) He knows that this account exists and therefore can focus his attack on this account. 2) He can send prepared links to the user to try a session-fixation. 3) Depending on your site, users do not want to be recognized as members. Surely there are other reasons as well, so i would not give any feedback about the existence of an account.