# "Password forgot" Php system

Tags: php, email, passwords

Which strategy is the best for recoving password.
Email the user a link to create a new password, overriding the current one? or
Email the user a randomly generated password, then ask them to change it?

Comment: Basicly it doesn't really matter. But I suggest making the link or temporary password only work within a short timeframe. Both ways are insecure though. If the registered email is hacked, they've got full access. I suggest using a combination of a secret question and asking them to fill their email address themselves to send it or something. In the end it still has security holes. But at least you can close them as much as you can.

Comment: Generating a random token and storing its hash in the database is the way to go. Since it is not derrived from other parameters it cannot be guessed, and because only its hash is stored it cannot be faked even if the database is leaking. I tried to explain the necessary steps in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18331345/575765).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one.

Create a form to get the user's email address.

If the user does not exist in your system, send an email to that address saying "someone tried to reset your password but it's not in our system".

If the user does exist in your system, create a **link** back to your site, and email the user that link. They click the link in the email and return to your site.

The **link** should look like this:

`https://example.com/reset-password?email=$usersEmail&hmac=$hmacOfTheirEmail`

Confirm that the email has not been tampered with by checking the [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).

To avoid user enumeration, return the same response from the form whether or not their email exists in your system.

Depending on your level of security...

- Log the user in
- Ask them one or more security questions
- Do multi-factor authentication

Then force the user to change their password

Some other answers/sites recommend storing tokens in the database. Ask [Mozilla](https://blog.perimeterx.com/bugzilla-cve-2015-4499/) how that went.

You could add some other parameters to that link such as **expiry time** and IP address. Make sure you include those in the HMAC too.

To prevent replay attacks, include a hash of the user's *old* (and forgotten) password in the link.

Comment: Your Mozilla link doesn't say anything about tokens. They were compromised (according to that article) because an employee reused his password on another site that was hacked.

Comment: @developerwjk fixed the link.

Comment: Sounds like it has a lot more to do with overloading the email address than with the token. Your hmac method would *not* fix Mozilla's bug, assuming you saved to the db first then generated the hmac from what was in the db, because the truncation of the email would have already happened, and you'd have the same vulnerability.

Comment: In the end it doesn't really matter what you do. The account security is up the user unless you know each user in person. If the email account is comprimised, all this won't help much. Personally I would create a token file on each account create. Lock account after x wrong passwords and send user an email that their token file will be able to unlock the account after 72 hours, so the user has a timeframe to contact the owner of the site if they didn't cause the wrong password attempts. Still not perfect. What if token lost? Etc etc. But than again, in the end security is up to account owner.

Comment: @developerwjk there is no need to write to the database to send a password reset, so you shouldn't. `assuming you saved to the db first` why would you do that?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will try to do it.

Comment: @icecub. 2FA solves the problem of their email being compromised, which is why I mentioned it. Locking out users is just a DoS attack on yourself.

Comment: Nevermind. I was referring to Mozilla's bug, which was with the registration process not password reset. And the main problem is they were assigning permissions based on a regex.

Comment: I'm not formilliar with that. But I wonder how it would know it's not me logging in on my hotmail account for example. It can't rely on an IP address. In my country, they're pretty much all dynamic and change every single day.

Comment: It would have been helpful if Neil had mentioned that the alternative proposal provides a means for DOSing accounts. Also the solution provided here is a bad idea, it is vulnerable to replay attacks. Use an expiring One Time Password not a simple hash

Comment: Alternative proposal = changing the password without authentication/verification of the request

Comment: This is the part I don't get: *"If the user does not exist in your system, send an email to that address saying "someone tried to reset your password but it's not in our system"."* - However, one can use almost any means of tokenizing/hashing for an email verification code; just as long as the database isn't compromised. Using a few parameters just as you suggested `?email=$usersEmail&hmac=$hmacOfTheirEmail` is good I find. This is what I do: A change password request is made, include in the message (you or someone made a request,if this wasn't you, simply ignore this email..) timestamp token.

Comment: If someone is trying to see if your email exists on a system (by attempting to reset the password for your account) would you rather know or not know ?