# Password Reset No Temporary Password Entry

Tags: security, authentication, url, passwords

I currently have a password reset with the following flow:

1. generate a temporary password
2. email it to the user
3. The user then clicks on a link in the email, taking them to a page where they can enter their temporary password along with a new one.

My question is, how can I *securely* achieve a password reset without making the user have to copy a nasty temporary password?

I have considered sending the password as a query string in the link in the email since HTTPS traffic is encrytped, but I have read that this is still a poor choice due to [various reasons](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/02/20/how-secure-are-query-strings-over-https/).

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks!

(I have purposely left out information about my stack as I am looking for a technology agnostic solution)

Comment: Look, you've got to send something. You can implement your own RSA where you send over the public key to the user's private key but for that, the system needs to be the same every time. Or, you can send half the temporary key where the other half is made of user's 8-char from email ID and date of birth in a certain format- you can inform him this through the same email you send for account recovery.

Comment: I wouldn’t let those reasons stop you with appropriate precautions like long strings for entropy and strict server checking (expire after some time, don’t allow reuse, etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I provide password reset functionality in a secure way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325681/how-can-i-provide-password-reset-functionality-in-a-secure-way)